# Change color in plotly bar graph

Tags: python, pandas, plotly, plotly-express

How can I change in plotly express the color of a specific bar in a bar graph.
For example, I want to change the color to purple , to the German Shephard (from the breed).

```
fig = px.bar(data_frame=df, x="quantity", y="dogs", orientation='h', color='dogs',hover_name='breed',)
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You can make a `discrete_color_map` dictionary like this:

```
color_discrete_map = {'German Shephard': 'rgb(255,0,0)'}
```

And pass it into your parameters when creating the bar chart like this:

```
fig = px.bar(data_frame=df, x="quantity", y="dogs", orientation='h', color='dogs',hover_name='breed',color_discrete_map = color_discrete_map)
```

Here is the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.bar.html).

Comment: No problem! If my answer worked, please accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: for some reason it is not working!

Comment: That's okay, there might be some glitch.

Comment: found it ...thanks!